# Create a teamID for unique team

Tags: sql, db2

So I have a table that shows an employee and all teammembers for that employee like this

```
empl    team_member
a       b
a       c
b       a
b       c
c       a
c       b 
x       z
z       x
y       w
y       q
w       y
w       q
q       y
q       w
```

what I ideally want would be to make a view that looks like this

```
empl    team
a       1
b       1
c       1
x       2
z       2
y       3
w       3
q       3
```

So looking at the first table you can see that A and C are related and C and A are related which is the same thing. I want to take each combation and just make an ID to say those people belong in the same team. anyone know how I can go about transforming the first table data into the second using DB2?

Comment: Don't know specifically about DB2, but you'll need a separate `team` table that has a PK column (e.g. `id`) in addition to `name` and then create a foreign key column, `team_id` in the `empl` table that references the `team.id` column. In addition, you'll need to migrate the data and update the client code as you can't simply change the underlying database and expect everything to immediately fit.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't actually have a table that lists the teams. All I have is the first table showing the relationship between empl1 and his/her team_members. Problem is I need a quick way to just pull everyone on the same team

Comment: Can't you create the table? Changes to the database, even if it's simply updating an existing column name, inevitably cascade to other areas of the system (e.g. other queries, code using it, etc.), especially if the database already has data in a production environment. I'm not sure what you expect of a "quick" way, but "quick" is usually followed by "bad idea". In your case, you're clearly trying to change the type of data stored in the column.

Comment: I was hoping for a clever solution that didn't result in me manually having to create the team ID relationship.

Comment: So you're hoping to update the underlying database schema/structure and that other areas of your system "don't notice"?

Comment: No I was hoping to make a view of the 2nd one since it will be more usable to work with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120749/discussion-between-ray-and-wizuriel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to get what you want:

```
select empl, dense_rank() over(order by case when min_m < empl then min_m else empl end) as team
from (
  select empl, min(team_member) as min_m
  from my_table
  group by empl
) as a
```

But I strongly agree with ray - having a table with all possible relations is a VERY bad design.

1. It is very excessive. For example, if you will have team with 100 members your table will contains 100*99 = 9900 rows. While in good design it will be only 101 rows (1 for team and 100 for employees).
2. It is easy to get inconsistency in such table. For example you accidently may get situation where A is a teammate of B, but not vice versa.

Possibly you have to maintain new tables and replace current table by view to provide some compatibility.